# Copying data from server to my project to prevent broken links and altering original data?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, copy, file-path

I recently started at a new company and am working on updating their trail maps. The GIS database that I have inherited is quite the mess. I am using ArcGIS Pro and I keep running into broken data links within their old projects. As I embark on creating my own projects, I am looking for advice on how to prevent this from happening within my projects.

For the trail maps I am creating, many will use the same shapefiles. These shapefiles are currently hosted on a server that is accessible to everyone in the organization. Is it best practice to create a copy of each file I need for each separate project? For example, have a copy of a roads shapefile in each project folder rather than use the original on the server. I want to make sure I am not altering the original file within the server and that I am preventing broken links in the future.

I am relatively new to working with GIS.

Comment: No, it's not best practice to use shapefiles at all, much less from a central file share. But it also isn't best practice to make tons of local copies. A centralized database would be best practice. Which RDBMS is highly *opinion-based* (and dependent on the skill set(s) of those involved). If you have an Enterprise license, all databases are on the table; if you don't, then PostgreSQL/PostGIS has the most functionality out of the box (though it still requires above a Basic Pro license). This sort of discussion-oriented question is a better fit elsewhere (including Esri's Community).